# Pyinstaller does not include module

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I am currently working on a small graphical python programm and I am using PyQT. My current goal is to pack the programm in an executable for distribution to other users.

I have chosen the tool pyinstaller for this task. I am using the command `pyinstaller --clean --hidden-import qtpy --onefile -n Monitor3 main.py` for packaging. The command generates an exe file but I see the following error in the logs `ERROR: Hidden import 'qtpy' not found`. I have verified that pyqt is installed via pip.

The following versions are installed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdtJL.png)
I use Python 3.7.5 .

If I run the generated executable file anyway I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qtpy'
[9676] Failed to execute script main
```

My question is how to solve this issue and get the executable running on multiple systems.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using pyqt while executing the command. Pyinstaller supports PyQT and it comes with it. So you don't need to mention it in command.

Try:

```
pyinstaller --clean --onefile -n Monitor3 main.py
```

Comment: I used that command first and added the rest aftwerwards out of desperation. I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Try using python 3.4 instead of python 3.7